# What is the fastest jQuery v1.4.4 Ajax content respond way by server-side?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, jquery, server-side

What is the fastest jQuery v1.4.4 Ajax content respond way by server-side? I use PHP and MySQL.

Do I have to convert MySQL data to JSON or XML format? Or is there simpler way to have fastest Ajax respond by MySQL?

I might to use jQuery Address [State](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/)  for it *- https://github.com/asual/jquery-address*, but seems it has to load-in a full html file just for to update small peaces of content data.

Comment: Fastest in what sense? To transport how much data?

Comment: Fastest in what sense? Unless you need to support 9600b modems, this sounds a bit like micro-optimization to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preparing JSON would be a bit faster, then XML, and it will be smaller and faster sent to client.

But really, I would focus on MySQL performance in your case. Selecting data will be times and times slower than sending a result via ajax.

Comment: What did you mean with jQuery Ajax MySQL performance? Could you give me some code example? Thanks!

Comment: I see that Twitter, Facebook, Google Instant etc. uses JSON.